Error com.google.android.gms
Me sale este error a la hora de ejecucion y no soy capaz de quitarlo.
Su compilacion es compileSdk 33 y minSdk 26 por si os hace falta
E/GoogleApiManager: Failed to get service from broker. 
java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.

Las dependencias son
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.4'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:20.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:1.19.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'

}
Tabbien por si os  face falta :
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

}
